# How to get multiple vouts in one RPC call?

Tags: transactions, bitcoind, json-rpc

Is there an RPC call to get more (or better all) vouts for given transaction?
Iterating over each one takes a lot of network time.

```
gettxout txid 0
gettxout txid 1
gettxout txid 2
gettxout txid 3 -> returns empty, so last one
```

"getrawmempool True" doesn't have vout addresses with amounts.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can get the entire transaction using `getrawtransaction`. This will include all vouts.

Comment: Yeah but it's raw hex, would you know a python parser for it? Segwit I guess is also encoded differently from legacy.

Comment: There is a a `verbose` parameter to have it be decoded by bitcoind and returned as json. See the [help text](https://bitcoincore.org/en/doc/22.0.0/rpc/rawtransactions/getrawtransaction/).

Comment: That works great thanks! Although it requires block hash too.